# Получить числа из строки python

Tags: python

строка: "5 из 19".
Нужно получить числа 5 и 19

Comment: re.findall(r'\d+','5 из 19') даст
        
['5', '19']

Comment: `'5 из 19'.split(' из ')` тоже даст ['5', '19']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a="5 из 19"
b=a.split()
c=[]
for i in b:
    if(i.isdigit()):
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```

если нужно вернуть прямо числа, а не строки с числами:

```
a="5 из 19"
b=a.split()
c=[]
for i in b:
    if(i.isdigit()):
        c.append(int(i))
print(c)
```

и если захочется вернуть не только целые числа:

```
a="5.78 из 19.38 да на 385"
b=a.split()
c=[]
for i in b:
    try:
        c.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        continue
print(c)
```

Comment: `for i in range(0,len(b)):` - это не питоновский стиль, надо перебирать сразу b в таких случаях как у вас, когда внутри цикла используется только b[i]: `for d in b:`

Comment: @CrazyElf , вы правы, поправил)